# How to convert element of variant to std::string ( c++ )

Tags: c++, c++17

How to convert element of variant to std::string??

```
void Function(const std::string str)
{
~~
}

std::variant<std::string, int, float> a{ 32 };
```

i should pass element of a to Function.
i can't change argument of Function. and i don't wanna add any helper function.

i just wanna convert element of a to string.
i tried many ways. but everything didn't works.
i know i can do this through `std::get<std::string>(a)`, `std::get<int>(a)`, `std::get<float>(a)`
but i need many try catch statements to do this.

i wanna know more clever ways.

Comment: `std::variant` doesn't work this way. It's not a magical wand to convert types to each other. It's simply a container, which can store *a single object* of one of the specified types.

Comment: To convert `int` to `string` you can use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and to do that backwards there is [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::visit` with some `if constexpr`s. If the variant holds a string, no conversion required; just call `Function`. Otherwise use `std::to_string` to convert a numeric argument:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

template<class> inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;

void Function(const std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::variant<std::string, int, float> a{ 32 };

    std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
            return Function(arg);
        else if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
            return Function(std::to_string(arg));
        else 
            static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
    }, a);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8jKe9d)

Comment: can you let me know why  std::decay_t is needed?

Comment: @hour30000 `std::decay_t` gives you the base data type, removing const and reference. That makes comparison easier inside your `std::visit` function call.

Answer (score 1):

To get the active element of a variant, regardless of its type, use `visit`. In order to visit the variant, you'll need a template function that can accept all of the contained types. That template can convert the argument to a string, for example using `std::to_string`, and pass that as an argument to `Function`.

Comment: Ironically `std::visit` is a helper function. Maybe the OP is willing to use a helper function written for them.

Comment: can you tell me how to use visit with template function, i  tried [](auto&& v){std::string{v}~~~~ } but it didn't works, because type of v isn't known inside of  visitor function

Comment: The type is known. The type is `decltype(v)`. It doesn't work because you cannot convert int or float to string like that. See my answer for a suggestion.